# Wordpress - disable auto <p> tag for part of a post/page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation where the use of the auto < p > is already used everywhere in different posts so I don't wan to turn it off using remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); in the template. I would like to turn off the auto < p > tag insertion for a part of a page like this

```
****PAGE****
remove_auto_p
<style>
...
</style>
<script>
...
</script>
insert_auto_p_again

Here's some post text :)

****/PAGE****
```

See more about this problem here if I am not clear enough (feel free to improve this question). 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-automatic-p-and-br-tags-in-html-editor

(Also I don't want to tweak the actual theme code because there's allot of updates to it - perhaps I could tweak this with some sort of plugin coding instead. )

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the_content function this function includes

tag it self. Use get_the_content() with this you can use with any tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - please make a little bit of an answer to the question if possible - or edit my question to improve it if get_the_content() should be used instead somehow. thanks

Comment: Where you exactly using this ? do you want to display content from editor without <p> tag ? i had same problem so here is what i did...

before : 

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

After : 

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<php echo get_the_content(); // This will only return content without extra tags. ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

Maybe it will be useful if not please tell me what you exactly want to do.

Comment: I don't know why text is so messed in stack overflow while commenting.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I only want to turn of the auto-p for a part of a post/page since there's allot of posts already that has layouts that are dependent on the "darn" auto <p>.